# Why does segmentation fault occur at pop {pc} of end of inline assembly function?

Tags: arm, inline-assembly

```
void func(int a, int b){
    asm(
        "func_:\n\t"
        "push {lr}\n\t"
        "sub sp, sp, #20\n\t" // prolog is done
        "add sp, sp, #20\n\t" // restore sp
        "pop {pc}\n\t"
        :

        :

        :
        "r0", "r1", "r2"
    );
}
```

in this code, segmentation fault occurs at pop {pc} for epilog of function

I really wonder why segmentation fault occurs at pop {pc} which is very very simple work. Can you explain me why and how to make function in inline assembly code including prolog of function and epilog of function?

Comment: I think you answered your own question - the compiler's prologue and epilogue are still there, so it won't work when you run their prologue but skip their epilogue.  Disassemble or single-step the code and you'll see. Also `lr` could potentially have been clobbered before your code gets control.  If you want the compiler to omit its prologue/epilogue, so that your asm statement is the entire code of the function, use [`__attribute__((naked))`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-Function-Attributes.html#ARM-Function-Attributes).